# Aunque y el modo verbal

Tags: subjuntivo

Un autor de una gramática española realizó un "análisis frecuencial", mejor dicho quería investigar qué modo se utiliza frecuentemente en las oraciones concesivas después de la conjunción *aunque* – indicativo o subjuntivo. El resultado indica que en 44 de 51 casos se usa el subjuntivo.

Me gustaría saber vuestra opinión: ¿Os parece razonable este análisis? Sabemos que el subjuntivo depende mucho de la actitud del hablante. Y si analizo un texto narrativo en el que se trata de acontecimientos reales o dificultades reales y el hablante está muy seguro de la concesión, entonces uso el indicativo, ¿verdad?

¿Se puede generalizar que el subjuntivo es el modo "preferido" después de *aunque*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Más que de la actitud del hablante, el uso del indicativo o del subjuntivo dependerá, respectivamente, de la certeza o mera probabilidad de la proposición introducida por "aunque":

- Aunque **llueve**, iré al picnic. (Está lloviendo, pero iré de todos modos.)
- Aunque **llueva**, iré al picnic. (Iré al picnic sea que llueva o no: cabe la posibilidad de que no llueva.)

Comment: gracias x la respusta pero lo que quería saber es si es razonable ANALIZAR la frecuencia del uso de un modo después de una cierta conjunción. P.ej. en una oración temporal si nos referimos a una acción en futuro, siempre utilizamos el subjuntivo (o imperativo) ya q expresamos una acción probable o hipotética (Cuando vaya a la tienda, compraré pan). PUNTO. El indicativo no se usa. Pero con la conjunción „aunque“ sí podemos utilizar ambos modos y el resultado de tal análisis dependería del CONTEXTO en el que las oraciones analizadas son utilizadas. 
uff me estoy explicando muy mal, ¿verdad? :/

Comment: @Aurora Personalmente no le veo la utilidad a esos análisis de frecuencia de uso salvo que el objetivo sea determinar la mayor o menor idiomaticidad de una palabra o frase. En este caso, ambos modos son correctos e idiomáticos. El hecho de que el subjuntivo ocurra con mayor frecuencia no lo hace preferible frente al indicativo: simplemente se trata de dos usos diferentes de "aunque".

Comment: Eso es lo que pensaba pero necesitaba que alguien me lo confirmara. Muchas gracias : )

Answer (score 1):

Lo que realmente observó el autor es que la palabra 'aunque' se usa con mayor frecuencia en oraciones concesivas que en oraciones adversativas.